# Initialize bootstrap modal in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am really new to javascript so please be gentle. I am trying to use bootstrap front end library to automatically open a pop up page with instructions on how to use my site. I can make the modal show on page load but that's all it shows. I want to show it over my regular page and then users can then dismiss it after they read the instructions. I don't know how to make it happen. I am not using regular HTML pages on my site. I am using Omeka CMS. What I understand I need to do is the following but I don't know how to actually do it. I need to:

1. put the markup for the modal in a custom show.php file
2. put the code to initialize the modal in script.js file (does it have to be script.js? I'm already using script.js for something else)

Right now I have all the code in show.php which shows the modal but not over my actual page and once you dismiss the dialog nothing happens. So somehow I need alter the show.php and create script.js file to make it work as intended. I don't know what code to put in script.js and I don't know how/where to call the script.js file.

This is the php that shows my modal but not in the way I want to use it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"     src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
 </script>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Modal -->

  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
</body>
</html>
```

I would appreciate any help anyone can provide. Thank you

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Your "modal" is an entire webpage. You need to strip out everything BUT the modal code and then just include that. Be sure to include all references to other libraries, etc on the referring page.

Comment: `This is the php that shows my modal but not in the way I want to use it`  tell us how do you want to use it ???

Your code snippet shows the modal as it should

Comment: I want the modal to pop up on top of my homepage. Right now all it does when I open the page is show me the modal and a blank page behind it and when I dismiss the modal all I have is a blank page.  What I want is the a modal on top of my page like here: http://neatline.dclure.org/neatline/show/declaration-of-independence  Once you close the modal you have the actual page.  Mine doesn't do that.  I looked at the way this guy made it but I can't figure it out.  Here is his code: https://github.com/davidmcclure/neatlight/tree/master/neatline/exhibits/themes/declaration-of-independence

Comment: Joe, but how do I do that using javascript file?  I was told I need to create script.js file (but I am already using script.js file for something else) and initialize the modal in that script.js file and then use show.php to put the modal markup there.  What is the code I put in script.js?  Is this enough $('#myModal').modal('show')  Can I use something else other than script.js?